# Using `/exec` directory in R packages for R scripts for reproducible research

Tags: r, package, gnu-make, executable, reproducible-research

For my research project I want to use a `make`-based workflow but also deliver the project in the form of a package. Thus, I want to put reusable functions in the `/R` directory for others to access but also use R scripts executable from the command line to do the actual analysis (generate and clean datasets, create plots, etc.), with `make` tracking the relationships among files and rebuilding what is necessary.

In packages, supposedly the `/exec` directory is meant for executable files. I'm wondering if putting my executable scripts in this directory would be appropriate.

Comment: Yes ... but place the source into `inst/exec/` so that it gets installed as `exec/`.  There are _numerous_ examples of doing this.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I thought `exec/` was one of those directories to avoid putting in `inst/` since it's a part of a package's structure: see ["Installed Files" from *R Packages*](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html). As a test I built a package that uses `exec/` and put a `.R` file in it and that structure was preserved. I would also be bothered by doing this since it seems I would need to rebuild the package and refer to a file in `exec/` in every `make` recipe when the file is actually in `inst/exec/` when I'm working with the unbuilt project.